# Progressive huffman table

Tags: jpeg

Do anyone of you know of a defacto standard huffman table for progressive jpeg encoding? There's examples of tables for baseline encoding in the standard that a lot of implementations use that seem to be adequate for most uses in regards of symbol frequency and so on but I can't seem to find one for progressive encoding that includes the symbols `EOB1` through `EOB14`.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of such a table. The approach is to do two passes over the data and find the best table for the scan in questions.